# Получить объект button, зная только класс svg внутри него

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, css-selectors

На странице есть несколько кнопок. Внутри кнопок есть div и svg.

```
<button class="wpOab  " type="button"><div class="QBdTU B5bH7"><svg class="news" color="#8e8e8e" fill="#8e8e8e" height="24"
...
</svg>
</div>
</button>
```

Классы генерятся случайно, один отличительный момент, что svg внутри кнопок имеет class="news".
И нужно через document.querySelector(".myclass"); получить не объект svg, а конкретно его родительский объект button. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
let newsSvg = document.querySelector('.news');

let res = newsSvg.closest('button');

console.log(res);
```

```html
<button class="wpOab" type="button">
  <div class="QBdTU B5bH7">
    <svg class="news">
    </svg>
  </div>
</button>
```